# Play - oracle 10g : PersistenceException: ERROR executing DML bindLog[] error[ORA-00001: Unique key constraint violation (PLAY.PK_COMPANY)\n

Tags: java, playframework, oracle10g, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm trying to use oracle 10g and ebeans for the "computer database" sample application of plesk. But when I try to insert a new computer on the database, I get this error :

```
[PersistenceException: ERROR executing DML bindLog[] error[ORA-00001: Unique key constraint violation (PLAY.PK_COMPANY)\n ]]
```

at the following line :

```
{ 
 Form<Computer> computerForm = form(Computer.class).bindFromRequest();
        if(computerForm.hasErrors()) {
            return badRequest(createForm.render(computerForm));
        }
       computerForm.get().save(); //HERE
        flash("success", "Computer " + computerForm.get().name + " has been created");
       return GO_HOME;
}
```

Here you have my object declaration :

```
@Entity 
@Table(name="COMPUTER")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "computer_seq", sequenceName = "computer_seq")
public class Computer extends Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Column(name="name")
    public String name;

    @Column(name="introduced")
    public String introduced;

    @Column(name="discontinued")
    public String discontinued;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    public Company company;

    /**
     * Generic query helper for entity Computer with id Long
     */
    public static Finder<Long,Computer> find = new Finder<Long,Computer>(Long.class, Computer.class); 

    /**
     * Return a page of computer
     *
     * @param page Page to display
     * @param pageSize Number of computers per page
     * @param sortBy Computer property used for sorting
     * @param order Sort order (either or asc or desc)
     * @param filter Filter applied on the name column
     */
    public static Page<Computer> page(int page, int pageSize, String sortBy, String order, String filter) {
        return 
            find.where()
                .ilike("name", "%" + filter + "%")
                .orderBy(sortBy + " " + order)
                .fetch("company")
                .findPagingList(pageSize)
                .getPage(page);
    }

}
```

**EDIT 1:**
I tried different `GeneratedValue strategy` like `AUTO` and `IDENTITY` but nothing work....

**EDIT 2:**
I tried to use `Sequence` strategy but it's not working too :

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "computer_seq", sequenceName = "computer_seq", initialValue=1, allocationSize=100)
[...]
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="computer_seq")
    public Long id;
```

**EDIT 3:**
Here you have the company entity :

```
@Entity 
@Table(name="COMPANY")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "company_seq", sequenceName = "company_seq", initialValue=1, allocationSize=100)
public class Company extends Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Column(name="name")
    public String name;

    /**
     * Generic query helper for entity Company with id Long
     */
    public static Model.Finder<Long,Company> find = new Model.Finder<Long,Company>(Long.class, Company.class);

    public static Map<String,String> options() {
        LinkedHashMap<String,String> options = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
        for(Company c: Company.find.orderBy("name").findList()) {
            options.put(c.id.toString(), c.name);
        }
        return options;
    }

}
```

I tried with a `SEQUENCE strategy` and `AUTO strategy` and it's not working too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error show up when ur save duplicate id on same table

check id value before save. @see http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00001.php

sory in my english. :D

Edit :

> Unique key constraint violation (PLAY.PK_COMPANY) try to check COMPANY entity for autoGenerate Sequence too.

Edit :

> change Company Generate to @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO,generator="company_seq") or change to @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="company_seq")

Comment: Yeah thank you I know that.... What I need is how to fixe it on my code because no `generatedvalue strategy` is working

Comment: oh sory, plz change to  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="computer_seq") when u need to use sequence and set it initial and allocatesize @SequenceGenerator(name="computer_seq",sequenceName = "computer_seq", initialValue=1, allocationSize=100)

Comment: check current max id by `select max(id) from computer` and then ALTER SEQUENCE computer_seq MAXVALUE `max_id_u_have_get+1`;

Comment: I did ALTER SEQUENCE computer_seq MAXVALUE 1000... but it failed again... :(

Comment: Unique key constraint violation (`PLAY.PK_COMPANY`) try to check COMPANY entity for autoGenerate Sequence too.

Comment: not working too.... And I don't understand why when I'm adding a new computer, I get an error with the Company primary key....

Comment: change Company Generate to @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO,generator="company_seq") or change to @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="company_seq")

Comment: if it not work try to increment company_seq by `ALTER SEQUENCE company_seq MAXVALUE 1000`

Comment: Not working too.... But I'm not sure the problem is here : I'm trying to add a computer. Computer has a foreign key to company, so I think it's strange that I get an error about the PK of company.

Comment: I changed `@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)` for `@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="COMPANY_ID")` and now I get the following error : `[PersistenceException: ERROR executing DML bindLog[] error[ORA-01861: literal does not match format string\n ]]`... So I guess je problem with the PK is solved, isn't it ?

Comment: Ok problem solved !! thank you very much KongKungz... and welcome to stackoverflow :D